# while debug selenium code, it works and in run it doesn't work

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to webdriver. I am automating a site In that, I have to click on a button which opens a new page and after that, I am clicking on a drop down. The problem is If I click on debug, it works well i.e. it opens the page, but if I run the same script it doesn't open the page and even in the console it doesn't show an error for that but show the error for the drop down which will be clicked after opening the page. Can anyone help?

Comment: Add some wait http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: Your description is pretty nice, however, a working code snippet would be much more practical. As @Guy pointed out: Are you using implicit or explicit waits? If the element is not present on the page (yet?), it will raise an error...

Comment: Please consider showing us what you have done so far. Also specify which language bindings you're using and whether you're using any test frameworks i.e. TestNG..

Comment: provide the code and the error message

Comment: Sometimes the element is not visible. You could use execute JavaScript.